# Segmentation error in linked list on getting node info

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm using linked list(not built in), here I'm implementing a logic to compare the first character of the Node(info) and then returning the word..

By going through this I'm facing a Segmentation error on the line  **currN = currNode->getInfo();**

Here my program:

```
template<class T>
string LinkedList<T>::searching(T word) {
Node<T> *currNode = head;
string currN = currNode->getInfo();
while (currNode != NULL && currN[0] != word[0]){
currNode = currNode->getNext();
    currN = currNode->getInfo();//error in this line
}
if(currNode) {
    val=currNode;//storing the address in a private pointer
    string cur = currNode->getInfo();
    return cur;
}
else{
    return "";
}}
```

getInfo:

```
// in Node class 
 private:
  T info;
 template<class T>
 T Node<T>::getInfo()   //getter for info 
 {
return info;
 }
```

here I'm passing string in the variable **T word**. A little help is appreciated

Comment: Looks like you don't check whether currNode / head is `nullptr`. Also, you don't show the `getInfo()` function so we can't say whatever problems might be hidden in there

Comment: [mcve] please, and format that consistently if you want people (including yourself!) to read and understand it! Also, a full backtrace!

Comment: getInfo() is just getting the data stored in info in the form of string

Comment: then your head is probably nullptr, also I'd recommend to learn how to use a debugger to get more information on what's going on in such cases!

Comment: After this line `currNode = currNode->getNext();` your `currNode` will be null at the end of the list but you do `currN = currNode->getInfo();`

Answer (score 1):

When your code traverses node by node, when it reaches the end of the list, the next line you are still trying to call getInfo(), so it crashes.

`currNode = currNode->getNext(); currN = currNode->getInfo();`

Change this to,

`currNode = currNode->getNext(); if(NULL != currNode) currN = currNode->getInfo();`

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```cpp
string currN = currNode->getInfo();
while (currNode != NULL && currN[0] != word[0]){
currNode = currNode->getNext();
    currN = currNode->getInfo();//error in this line
}
```

with this:

```cpp
while (currNode != NULL && currNode->getInfo()[0] != word[0]){
    currNode = currNode->getNext();
}
```